# How to run java project from command line (works fine in eclipse, gradle)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'v got a simple java program. I'm developing in Eclipse, using gradle, and I'm logging with log4j2.  This all works fine.

When I come to run from the command line, I do a gradlew build which works, but when I run the jar I get an error:

```
java -jar build\libs\testproj.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
        at com.xxxxxx.practice.App.<clinit>(App.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

I can see a bunch of log4j files in my userprofile.gradle folder, and I could run a gradle dist task and then got and unzip the resulting zip file and then point at the contents of that, but if there some way of avoiding this?  Surely there's something I can add to the manifest or something so that I can run from the command line at will with no overhead?

To be clear, it's just the logging that has this problem.  Other than that it runs, the tests work etc from the command line, and the logging works fine from eclipse.

Comment: In the run configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ to get the command line used by Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger Thanks. I just tried using just the classpath part, and specified my jar as before but I get the same problem.  Also, even if that works, is that how you'd normally do it?  I was sort of expecting something like a gradle task which will do this sort of thing for me.  Otherwise I might be better off going down the 'building a dist' route, assuming that works.

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someplace in your eclipse project, you'll find a library (these end in `.jar`) named `log4j.jar` or `org.apache.logging-log4j.jar` or `log4j-api.jar` or something along those lines.

This jar contains the classes that are missing when you run this on the command line. Try it: `jar tvf log4j.jar` prints the contents of the jar and you'll find it contains, for example, `org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.class`.

During compilation *and* during running a java app, this class needs to be on the classpath. Eclipse is taking care of the compilation part of it.

If you run java as `java com.foo.ClassName`, the classpath is defined by the `-cp` parameter: `java -cp testproj.jar:log4j.jar com.foo.yourapp.TestApp` would work (use semicolon on windows instead). If you don't specify it, the system environment variable `CLASSPATH` is used, but you don't want that (you can run multiple java apps on one machine after all, so a global setting makes little sense).

If you run java using `java -jar myjar.jar` however, the classpath is solely taken from the jar file itself; inside the jar file is a file called `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and it contains (in text) key/value pairs. The relevant one is the `Class-Path: foo.jar bar.jar` entry: Space-separated listings of jar files, relative to the dir your jar is in.

**You cannot use the `-cp` option when using the `-jar` option; the `-cp` option is ignored**.

So, next steps:

1. I don't know if gradle made the Class-Path entry correctly. Best option is to use the `jar` or `zip` tool to unpack your jar to check that MANIFEST.MF file and see what's there. If there is, say, `Class-Path: lib/log4j.jar` in that file, then make sure that if testapp.jar is at `/Users/Dev123456/project/testapp.jar`, that that log4j jar is at `/Users/Dev123456/project/lib/log4j.jar`. If there is no class-path entry, then the error lies in your gradle config; you'd have to post your build.gradle file in that case.
2. There are 'striper plugins' which mix all the various jars together in one giant jar. This is usually a bad idea (it just makes the jar itself humongous, and makes builds take longer. If you're deploying java code to a server, you can manage the Class-Path entry by yourself, and if you are making a desktop app, you need an installer which... can manage the class-path stuff just as well. Really no reason to use stripers). I advise against using these.
3. Just run with `java -cp yourapp.jar:dep1.jar:dep2.jar com.foo.fullyqualified.ClassName` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your jar by specifying Log4j jar as well in classpath and then mention your MainClass from testproj.jar :

```
java -cp build\libs\testproj.jar:build\libs\log4j.jar com.package.MainClass
```